# How to change framerate in python using Camgear?

Tags: python, opencv, youtube, stream, live

My script intends to show a YouTube live stream

```
from vidgear.gears import CamGear
import cv2
url = 'https://youtu.be/o0Ryp4iWgOg'
stream = CamGear(source=url, y_tube =True,  time_delay=1, logging=True).start() 
# YouTube Video URL as input
print(stream.framerate)

while True:

frame = stream.read()

if frame is None:

    break
b = cv2.resize(frame, (800, 600), fx=0, fy=0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imshow("LiveVid", b)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if key == ord("q"):
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
stream.stop
```

After a few seconds the stream stops. I think the high frame rate causes this problem. So I want to change the frame rate. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to run this code, you have to turn url into other youtube live stream url